# Запрос с несколькими условиями в SQL

Tags: sql, запрос, access

У меня есть таблица MUSICIANS в которой есть поля с названием исполнителя, годом рождения, страной, и активностью (кто выступает, а кто нет. Это логическое поле). Задача такая: составить запрос к базе данных, при выполнении которого будут выдаваться на экран количество выступающих и закончивших выступления исполнителей в каждой из стран.

Я пыталась сделать хоть что-то, но никак не могу понять, как правильно задать условие.
Это то, что пока есть:

```
SELECT  COUNTRY, count(*) as Выступающие, count(*) as Закончившие выступать
FROM MUSICIANS where active = true or (where active = false) group by country ;
```

Не могли бы вы подсказать, как это сделать.

Comment: За исключением лишнего слова where у вас запрос active=true or active=false заведомо выдаст вообще все записи из БД. фактически это условие не нужно. А скорее всего вам нужно вместо count считать `sum(case active when true then 1 end)` ну и то же с false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT country,
       -SUM(active) [Выступающие],
       -SUM(NOT active) [Закончившие выступать]
FROM musicians 
GROUP BY country
```

В MS Access логическое поле в числовом контексте преобразуется в `0` для `FALSE` и в `-1` для `TRUE`.

Осталось их просуммировать по стране и нейтрализовать минус.